# PostgreSQL-Iterate over result of a query and make a select based on value of iteration

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have 3 tables Person, Address and Person_adress.

i'm writting a script with an array of address_code as entry.

the aim of the script is to  show the name and email of every person living in each address
Then, make some treatment base on every name,
Then make some treatment based on every email,
Then update the address

here is my script:

```
do $$ 

DECLARE 
-- L'ensemble des adresses  
address_codes varchar [] := '{"AF_X1", "AD_X3", "AC_S4"}';
v_code varchar; 
v_id_person varchar;    
v_firstname_person varchar;
    v_email varchar;


BEGIN   
FOREACH v_code in array address_codes
LOOP        
    FOR v_id_person IN SELECT pa.person_id from person_address pa, address a WHERE pa.address_id=a.id AND a.code=v_code
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Traitement de la personne %', v_id_person;
        -- Recuperation du nom de la personne
        SELECT pe.firstname INTO v_firstname_person from person pe where pe.id = v_id_person;
        SELECT pe.email INTO v_email from person pe where pe.id = v_id_person;
        RAISE NOTICE 'the firstname of person is %', v_firstname_person;

                   RAISE NOTICE 'the email of person is %', v_email;

        --Here is some treatment based on v_firstname_person value
    --Here I some treatment based on v_email value  
       END LOOP;    

      UPDATE address SET etat="DONE" where code = v_code;      
    END LOOP;       
END;

$$;
```

But the value of **v_firstname_person** is still NULL.

here is the output that i have

the firstname of person is ,NULL

i properly have values in my database;

How can i resolve this issue please;

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this.

Comment: Can't you just join persons to addresses in sql query? `select p.*, a.* from adresses as a join person_address pa on pa.address_id = a.id join person p on pa.person_id = p.id WHERE a.code = 'CODE'`

Comment: In fact, this is just an example. My Script I must complex than this one. I have to make a complex treatment based on each v_firstname_person

Comment: Thanks piotrekkr for your answers. The query I based on address_codes, an array. How can I use it in your answers please

Comment: @blaiso Try using `WHERE a.code = v_code`

Comment: @blaiso Sorry my previous comment was incorrect. Try using this condition `WHERE IN  (SELECT * FROM unnest(address_codes))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single loop to iterate over the rows in the person table.

To find them you can use an EXISTS condition using the array as a parameter for a WHERE clause:

```
do $$ 
DECLARE 
  -- L'ensemble des adresses  
  address_codes varchar [] := '{"AF_X1", "AD_X3", "AC_S4"}';
  v_firstname_person varchar;
  v_email varchar;
  l_prec record;
BEGIN   
  FOR l_prec in IN SELECT pe.*
                FROM person pe 
                WHERE EXISTS (select *
                              FROM person_address pa 
                                join address a on pa.address_id = a.id 
                              WHERE pe.ref_douane = pa.person_id
                                AND a.code = any(address_codes);
  LOOP
    -- not really necessary, but keeps your current variables
    v_firstname := l_prec.firstname;
    v_email := l_prec.email;

    RAISE NOTICE 'the firstname of person is %', v_firstname;
    RAISE NOTICE 'the email of person is %', v_email;

    --Here is some treatment based on v_firstname_person value
    --Here I some treatment based on v_email value  
  END LOOP;

  UPDATE address 
     SET etat='DONE' --<< String constants need single quotes, not double quotes
  where code = any(address_codes);
END;
$$;
```

---

Note that in your current code, these two statements:

```
SELECT pe.firstname INTO v_firstname_person from person pe where pe.id = v_id_person;
SELECT pe.email INTO v_email from person pe where pe.id = v_id_person;
```

can be combined to a single one:

```
SELECT pe.firstname, pe.email
   INTO v_firstname_person, v_email
from person pe 
where pe.id = v_id_person;
```